Record the mouse on a slider?
So I know that there is a way to record the mouse movement on an object. I activate Auto Keyframe, I select the object I want to move, I press play, press G or R, and as I move the mouse keyframes are dotted along the timeline and the object in question moves as my mouse moved.
However, is there a way to do this with sliders like Shape Keys or Focus Length? I tried to drag while playing, but it just jitters back to what the first keyframe is set to and no new keyframes are created. Would I need to create an in-scene slider?
